# How to collect JMX metrics from an EC2 instance and populate it in AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the below setup in place.

EC2 instance, with below packages installed to collect metrics

1. cloudwatch agent
2. cloudwatch plugin
3. collectd
4. collectd-java
5. collectd-generic-jmx
6. Elasticsearch

Now, my purpose is to collect Elasticsearch jmx related metrics (Heap Space Used, gc time, etc) and publish them to cloudwatch which I am unable to do.
I am able to scrape other metrics (mem, df, cpu) to cloudwatch but there are no traces of jmx metrics seen on cloudwatch.

Is it possible to collect elastic search jmx metrics, is my configuration correct, please help
I am new to jmx configuration.

Please find my collectd-cloudwatch.conf configuration

```
<Plugin "java">
JVMArg "-Djava.class.path=/usr/share/collectd/java/collectd-api.jar:/usr/share/collectd/java/generic-jmx.jar"
LoadPlugin "org.collectd.java.GenericJMX"
<Plugin "GenericJMX">
  <MBean "gc-count">
    ObjectName "java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,*"
    InstancePrefix "gc-"
    InstanceFrom "name"
    <Value>
      Type "derive"
      Table false
      Attribute "CollectionCount"
      InstancePrefix "count"
    </Value>
  </MBean>
   <MBean "gc-time">
    ObjectName "java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,*"
    InstancePrefix "gc-"
    InstanceFrom "name"
    <Value>
      Type "derive"
      Table false
      Attribute "CollectionTime"
      InstancePrefix "time"
    </Value>
  </MBean>
  <MBean "memory_pool">
    ObjectName "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,*"
    InstancePrefix "memory_pool-"
 InstanceFrom "name"
    <Value>
      Type "memory"
      Table true
      Attribute "Usage"
    </Value>
  </MBean>
   <MBean "memory-heap">
    ObjectName "java.lang:type=Memory"
    InstancePrefix "memory-heap"
    <Value>
      Type "memory"
      Table true
      Attribute "HeapMemoryUsage"
    </Value>
  </MBean>
  <MBean "memory-nonheap">
    ObjectName "java.lang:type=Memory"
    InstancePrefix "memory-nonheap"
    <Value>
      Type "memory"
      Table true
      Attribute "NonHeapMemoryUsage"
    </Value>
  </MBean>
   <MBean "thread">
    ObjectName "java.lang:type=Threading"
    InstancePrefix "threading"
    <Value>
      Type "gauge"
      Table false
      Attribute "ThreadCount"
      InstancePrefix "count"
    </Value>
  </MBean>
  <MBean "thread-daemon">
    ObjectName "java.lang:type=Threading"
    InstancePrefix "threading"
    <Value>
      Type "gauge"
      Table false
      Attribute "DaemonThreadCount"
      InstancePrefix "count-daemon"
    </Value>
  </MBean>
  <Connection>
    ServiceURL "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9200/ ---> elasticsearch running with https
    Collect "memory_pool"
    Collect "memory-heap"
    Collect "memory-nonheap"
    Collect "gc-count"
    Collect "gc-time"
    Collect "thread"
    Collect "thread-daemon"
    User "kibana"
    Password "kibana"
  </Connection>
</Plugin>
</Plugin>
```

Here is the error which I am getting in collectd logs

```
[2020-04-19 10:18:46] [error] GenericJMX plugin: Evaluating `Connection' block failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No service URL was defined.
```

Comment: I believe the best way would be to use Prometheus. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights-Prometheus.html